# Excel Formula to Check if a Word Begins with a Keyword

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

As the picture shows, I have 3 keywords from cell A2 to A4: `a`, `bb`, and `ccc`.

I have 5 words to check, listed in B2:B6: `aa`, `bb`, `bc`, `cc`and `d`.

[image: question]

I'd like to check, for each word in Column B, that if it starts with one of the keyword.
The expected result is shown in Column C.

However I could not come out with a formula for that.

#### What I've tried

1. I tried the *match* function in Column D and E but it can only do an exact match, not a "begin with" logic.
2. I tried the *CountIf* function in Column F and G. It actually can do the reverse match - if any keyword start with the word in column B - but it cannot do the match I want.

So, how can I check a range of words if they contain a value from a given keyword list

Comment: athos you killing me with this, I don't like saying that I cannot figure something out in excel, but you would need to store variables to do this I think. This is a piece of cake in VBA. Sorry :(

Comment: @sgp667 thanks trying :) good news is the answer below works!

Comment: Could you please try to find a better title. "how to write such formula?" isn't very meaningful

Comment: @nixda how about now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Input the following array formula (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) into cell C3  and then drag it down. I extended your scenarios just a bit and it performs as expected.

```
=SUM(IF(LEFT(B3,LEN($A$3:$A$7))=$A$3:$A$7,1,0))
```

[image: Array if formula keyword search]